# MySQL performance_schema database is different after dump and reimport

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I got a whole MySQL ( 5.5.60-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) database dump and reimported into Mariadb (10.3.15-MariaDB-1:10.3.15+maria~bionic-log)

I have only 17 tables in mysql but in mriabd 52. I want to know why? Will it cause any problem? I am mainly migrating from mysql to mairdb.

Comment: Are you sure the MariaDB database was empty before importing there? You should identify one of the new [unexpected] tables and see if it's in the dump file.

Comment: I installed new mariadb in ubuntu 18

Comment: Read up what the performance_schema actually is. TL;DR: no worries, it's normal that a newer version of MariaDB/MySQL has more performance_schema tables.

Comment: i removed that other comment as i read performance_schema and *"I have only 17 tables in mysql but in mriabd 52"* how did you do the count i mean the query with that.. As if might be that MariaDB has more defualt performance_schema views..

Comment: *"it's normal that a newer version of MariaDB/MySQL has more performance_schema tables."* very true but technical those tables are views @fancyPants  that mean the topicstarter can execute this. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME= DATABASE() AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TYPE'` this count should be the same on both servers.

Comment: You should not reload `information_schema`, `performance_schema`, or `mysql`.